# What's the meaning of faint text in the Firefox dev tools inspector?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

What does it mean when there is "faint text" in the Firefox dev tools inspector, like the .tab-pane divs in the .project_tab_content area:

[image]

This corresponds to some Bootstrap stuff that is working everywhere except Firefox, so I'm a little suspicious...  Thanks!

Comment: Do the grey elements all have `display: none;`?

Comment: If you are talking about the markup with less opacity, then yes, these are the elements present in DOM but not rendered (usually because of display:none rule)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faded elements mean they are not visible. This can be due to some CSS like `display: none` or their dimensions being 0x0. See also the [hint at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_and_edit_HTML#HTML_tree) regarding this.